# Series with integral sequence as coefficients

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I'm working on a question. It began by asking me to show that:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(2-\cos\theta)^2}=\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$$

and I've managed that. However, the next part of the question is to show that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(2-\cos\theta)^n}\right)t^n=2\pi\left(1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{(1-t)(3-t)}}\right)$$

and here I get stuck. I know the coefficient for $n=2$, and for $n=0$ it is trivially $2\pi$. I can't get the integrals into something related to the integrals that I already know (I've tried that by integration by parts). I can't exchange the order of summation and integration because the integrand is not absolutely convergent (and if do I find that it integrates to 0).

So any clues as to how I can solve this?

Comment: When $|t| < 1$, it is legal to exchange summation and integration.   Furthermore, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{t}{2-\cos\theta}\right)^n$ converges uniformly to $\displaystyle\;1 + \frac{t}{2-t-\cos\theta}\;$ over  $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(2-\cos\theta)^n} = 2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{du}{(2-u)^n\sqrt{1-u^2}} $$
then by multiplying both sides by $t^n$ and summing over $n\geq 0$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}t^n\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(2-\cos\theta)^n} = 2\pi+2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{t}{(2-t-u)\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du $$
The last integral is simple to compute, given the first point:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{du}{(2-t-u)\sqrt{1-u^2}} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(4-2t)du}{((2-t)^2-u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$
and:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{((2-t)^2-u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(2-t)^2-\sin^2\theta}=\frac{\pi}{2|t-2|\sqrt{(t-1)(t-3)}}.$$
An alternative approach is to directly manipulate the generating function for [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help. So it was a question of interchanging the order of integration and summation - it looks like I got that wrong when I tried it.